# Laravel coloca argumento em fonte? há como tirar?

Tags: laravel, npm, font

```js
        <pre>fonts/vendor/materialize-css/dist/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff2?1561b424aaef2f704bbd89155b3ce514  65.4 kB          [emitted]

   fonts/vendor/materialize-css/dist/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff2?1f35e6a11d27d2e10d28946d42332dc5  63.1 kB          [emitted]

  fonts/vendor/materialize-css/dist/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff2?3c37aa69cd77e6a53a067170fa8fe2e9  64.3 kB          [emitted]
   fonts/vendor/materialize-css/dist/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff?ea36cd9a0e9eee97012a67b8a4570d7b  89.7 kB          [emitted]
fonts/vendor/materialize-css/dist/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff2?5136cbe62a63604402f2fedb97f246f8  64.8 kB          [emitted]
 fonts/vendor/materialize-css/dist/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff?3cf6adf61054c328b1b0ddcd8f9ce24d  89.8 kB          [emitted]
    fonts/vendor/materialize-css/dist/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff?44b78f142603eb69f593ed4002ed7a4a  88.1 kB          [emitted]
  fonts/vendor/materialize-css/dist/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff?cf4d60bc0b1d4b2314085919a00e1724  90.6 kB          [emitted]
   fonts/vendor/materialize-css/dist/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff2?c0f1e4a4fdfb8048c72e86aadb2a247d  64.8 kB          [emitted]
    fonts/vendor/materialize-css/dist/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff?eed9aab5449cc9c8430d7d258108f602  90.3 kB          [emitted]
                                                                                    \js\app.js  1.63 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  \js\app
                                                                                  \css\app.css   210 kB       0  [emitted]         \js\app</pre>a
```

Laravel Inclui um argumento ao acessar as fontes, o problema é que estas fontes estão resultando em erro usando o cache do html 5, alguem sabe como remover este argumento? para que serve? e como posso resolver o conflito no html5 cache caso não tenha como tirar ou seja importante?

Comment: Como você está chamando essas fontes?

Comment: Dentro do arquivo css. eles tão sendo chamados lá.

Comment: Só remove! .... e outra não é o Laravel que faz isso ....

Comment: Remover o que? não sei onde remover, mas preciso das fontes. Algumas se relaciona aos icones da aplicação, tó usando materialize.

Comment: Só remover os paramentos dessas fontes do arquivo `.css`! apesar que isso não teria que te atrapalhar em nada!

Comment: Não entendi, o problema que o materialize tem muitos arquivos, ele fala de um arquivo de rota, porem, não posso configurar manualmente.

Comment: Ele fala aonde? o que acontece, coloque isso na sua pergunta, o processo que ocasiona o problema!

Comment: Na hora de carregar o site, os Icons não carregam, mesmo os arquivos que o define estando no computador, e o cache não consegue pegar a pagina.

Comment: Você já debugou apertando F12 no navegador?

Comment: é exatamente assim que o erro acontecia. mas dei um jeito de resolver, coloquei cada uma das configurações para acessar pela rota, deixando os arquivos "de cara pra rua", mas resolveu o erro e o cache tá funcionando. 

Só deu um pouco mais de trabalho para colocar cada ponto onde havia link referenciando o site.

Comment: Já tentou um `php artisan cache:clear` e compilar novamente seu _js_?

Comment: Ainda não, vou tentar.... REspondo mais tarde.

Comment: Resolvi ultilizando a seguinte tecnica, referenciando a fonte ela estando na pasta public do sistema, assim, o laravel não coloca argumentos e funciona normalmente.